# How to parameterize an ellipse?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, parametric

I need to parameterize the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{2}+y^2=2$, so this is how I proceed:

I know that $a=2$ and $b=1$ (where $a$ and $b$ are the axis of the ellipse), so I parameterize as:
\begin{cases}
x=a\cos(t)\\
y=b\sin(t)
\end{cases}
and I get
\begin{cases}
x=2\cos(t)\\
y=\sin(t)
\end{cases}
but if I plot the parameterized curve and the equation those are not the same, I think that the cause it's the $=2$ in the equation but I don't know how to put it into the parameterized ellipse, can someone help me?

Comment: Other answers are correct, shortest explanation: set x=0 in your equation to see the y intercept is sqrt(2), not 1.

Comment: note $,b=\sqrt 2$,$a$ ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide by 2 and write the denominator of the $y$ term as $(\sqrt2)^2$:
$$\frac{x^2}{2^2}+\frac{y^2}{(\sqrt2)^2}=1$$
This gives the correct parametrisation:
$$x=2\cos t\qquad y=\sqrt2\sin t\qquad t\in[0,2\pi]$$

Comment: It's correct! I try divide by 2 but i used $a=4$ and $b=2$ without applying the sqrt so I didn't get the correct parametrization. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I know that $a=2$ and $b=1$ (where $a$ and $b$ are the axis of the ellipse)

Nope, they are NOT the semi-major and semi-minor axis. The equation needs to be reduced to

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $$

Notice the $1$ on the right side. So you need to divide your equation to get

$$ \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{2} = 1 $$